# Ensure parameter on generic method is base of paramater in the same class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic class defined as follows:

```
public abstract class BaseValidator<T> : IValidator<T> where T: IEntity
{
   //some methods and parameters here
   protected void Include<E>(IValidator<E> validator) where E : class , IEntity
   {
       if (typeof(E) != typeof(T).BaseType)
       {
            throw new ArgumentException($"Generic class Validator<T> must only Include Validators for base classes");
       }
       //Some business logic around connecting validators
   }
}
```

The method Include is designed to take in a Validator parameter, it uses this to bind validators to each other, similar to a chain of responsibiity of validators. I currently have run time checking to ensure that E is a base class of T but I would like to move this to compile time checking.

I have attempted to add on a second where clause to the method Include as follows:

```
where T:E
```

However visual studio complains that the method Include does not define a Type parameter 'T'

If I do define a type parameter I get a message stating that the type parameter 'T' has the same name as the type parameter on the outer class.

How can I ensure that the generic type passed into my method is the base class that my T implements?

---

Edit 1:

```
public class BankAccountValidator : BaseValidator<BankAccount>
    {
        public BankAccountValidator(IValidator<OwnedProduct> validator)
        {
            Include(validator);
            //Some logic here
        }
    }
```

In this case BankAccount implements OwnedProduct. So when a validate method is called on BankAccount it also calls validate on OwnedProduct.

I want to enforce that you cannot pass in to BankAccountValidator another BankAccountValidator or if I have a OwnedCredit type which BankAccount does not derive from that I cannot pass the OwnedCreditValidator in to the constructor.

There are a large number of validators and having it strongly typed like this would prevent me from running into runtime issues.

Comment: You cannot restrict class-level type parameter in method of that class, does not even make much sense. Say you were able to do that, now `T` should inherit from `E`. Then you add another method with some type parameter `F` and say `T` should inherit from it. Now `T` should inherit from both `E` and `F`.

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you should be able to change method signature to `protected void Include(IValidator<T> validator) {...}`? Because `T` is defined already? Maybe not getting it, though.

Comment: OK I deleted my Answer because I didn't get your question before.

Comment: Can you give a use case of your actual code (without compile time checking) to understand why you need this constraint?

Comment: @PedroPerez see my edit

Comment: It seems like you want to add a lot of interfaces and restrict the type that way for each inheritance chain: `IChildA : IParentA`, `IChildB : IParentB`. Which is probably not the solution you were looking for. Unless I'm not understanding this correctly. Edit: and change Include to restrict on `where E : class , IEntity, IChildx` depending on the parent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public abstract class BaseValidator<T, E> : IValidator<T> 
    where E: IEntity
    where T: E
{
   //some methods and parameters here
   protected void Include(IValidator<E> validator)
   {          
       //Some business logic around connecting validators
   }
}

public class BankAccountValidator : BaseValidator<BankAccount, OwnedProduct>
{
    public BankAccountValidator(IValidator<OwnedProduct> validator)
    {
        Include(validator);
        //Some logic here
    }
}
```

If OwnedProductValidator can validate himself, then:

```
public class OwnedProductValidator : IValidator<OwnedProduct>
{ 
    // IValidator interface implementation
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var ownedProductValidator = new OwnedProductValidator();                
        var bankAccountValidator = new BankAccountValidator(ownedProductValidator);
    }
}
```

If OwnedProductValidator needs some other class validation, then:

```
public class OwnedProductValidator : BaseValidator<OwnedProduct, SomeOtherClass>{}
```

Comment: How would I then use BaseValidator for my Base class? What would the second parameter be for OwnedProductValidator?

Comment: Sorry, I got side tracked with another issue and forgot to mark this as the answer. Rather than follow your code exactly I left the base validator as it was and created a secondary class which implements Base validator and has the inheritence restrictions. Thanks